# When will the layoutSubviews be called by the instance of UIScrollView for a scrolling action?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview

My question is actually about the timing that the layoutSubviews is being fired. Is it called when the scroll view starts to scroll? or, the scrolling is completed? or being fired during the scrolling?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fired on every frame of scrolling, every time the scroll view's bounds change (which can happen up to 60 times per second).  Eliza mentions this 14 minutes into the “Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views” video from [WWDC 2010](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).

Sometimes it's faster to just call `NSLog` from a method than to wait for someone to answer you on stackoverflow. ;^)

Comment: Thx rob, I'm new to iOS development, so I'm doing both the investigation and waiting for answer from stackoverflow simultaneously. I'm still having other problems of using the UIScrollView and trying to figure them out.

Comment: If you want to learn about scroll views, or any other part of iOS, I highly recommend Apple's developer videos.  In addition to the one I linked in my answer, there's also “Session 104 - Advanced Scroll View Techniques” from WWDC 2011 and “Session 223 - Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views” from WWDC 2012.

Comment: I understand the major design patterns and the Obj-C language used in the iOS development. However, I feel really hard to transit from the .Net framework and web development to iOS development under Apple frameworks. I'm very confused about the details. Feeling really upset.

Comment: hi @rob, would you mind helping me to take a look at another related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392867/why-does-the-uiscrollview-could-not-be-scrolled-in-the-ios-simulator