# Why does the UIScrollView could not be scrolled in the iOS simulator？

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I'm trying to get familiar with the `UIScrollView`. I try to set the `UIScrollView's contentSize`to  `full width` of the screen and `ten times` the `heigh`t of the screen in the corresponding `ViewController's viewDidLoad` method. However, when I tried to run it on the `iOS simulator`, I found that the view can't be `scrolled`. Please kindly help to give some hints & opinion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need To check  in your Code See

1)Check whether the UserInteraction enabled For The `UIScrollView` if not Please Do as

```
     [theScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

**EDIT**

2)Please Make Sure You have Enabled The Scrolling of `UIScrollView`

```
     theScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Thanks.

Comment: so, I can tease the UIScrollView without putting any content or subviews by just adjusting its contentSize, right?

Comment: @WilliamChoi sorry dude i could not understand you

Comment: In the storyboard, I put a view controller, and place an UIScrollView within it. There is a label on the scroll view. Then, In the implementation of the corresponding view controller class, I set the UIScrollView's contentSize to larger than the screen frame in the instance method "viewDidLoad". However, when debugging in the iOS simulator, I can't scroll the scrollView.

Comment: Try setting the content size in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.  Also you can set the content size in InterfaceBuilder in the inspector panel for the scrollView.